# Magento multi-site data migration. While merging new store needs to keep live existing stores/sites

Tags: magento-enterprise, database, migration, architecture

I am working on Magento enterprise edition. In which, two sites are already set up and working. Both of them are setup and configured by us. Now as per requirement client wants to add one more site in current environment but the tweak is we are not suppose to shut down existing site. Earlier while migration we used to close the stores.

Merging or Migration new site:
Following points are key areas

1. Migrate customer data -- No Issue
2. Migrate product data -- No Issue
3. Migrate reviews and rating -- No Issue
4. Configuration part -- No Issue
5. Migrate old site's orders -- Critical

We are finding solution for the 5th point. We have no issue with the coding part. We are using custom script and some configuration changes in the payment files so when orders create system do not deduct any amount from the customer's paypal or authorized account. Hence, no matter of what site is running or not payment process will not work while the Order Migration process is in progress. Our coding scenario is conflicting with client business perspective because they want site up and running 24x7 while migration process.

We are working on to resolve our conflicts in which we found two architectures which are suitable:

1. Master-Master
2. Master-Slave

We are not sure for following things:

1. Which approach or architecture is suitable for us?
2. What are the best practices for magento data migration?
3. How many more sites i can configured in single magento enterprise edition environment? Is there any limit?

Any new suggestion or approaches are welcome. Thanks in advance.

**NOTE**: Server is very highly configured. So environment setup is not an issue.

Comment: What does the database setup have to do with your questions? (BTW: use master/master) 

As I read through your post it seems your question is the best approach to import orders from an existing Magento site to another Magento site as a new store or website?

Comment: It's our logic. We thought that if database can be smart enough to handle communication (in terms of data) part then we can invest our time on coding side. We are setting up multi sites. One more question that how many multi sites can we set up in single magento environment?

Comment: The amount of sites depends on your server, your traffic, your sku count and your categories. The more you add of each the more server you need!